# Downside of using patched threading vs native gevent greenlets?

Tags: python, gevent, python-multithreading

My understanding is that once I have called gevent.monkey.patch_all(), the standard threading module is modified to use greenlets instead of python threads.  So if I write my application in terms of python threads, locks, semaphores etc, and then call patch_all, am I getting the full benefit of gevent, or am I losing out on something compared with using the explicit gevent equivalents?

The motivation behind this question is that I am writing a module which uses some threads/greenlets, and I am deciding whether it is useful to have an explicit switch between using gevent and using threading, or whether I can just use threading+patch_all without losing anything.

To put it in code, is this...

```
def myfunction():
  print 'ohai'

Greenlet.spawn(myfunction)
```

...any different to this?

```
import gevent.monkey
gevent.monkey.patch_all()
def mythread(threading.Thread):
  def run(self):
    print 'ohai'

mythread().start()
```

Answer (score 2):

At least your will loose some of greenlet-specific methods: link, kill, join etc.
Also you can't use threads with, for example, gevent.pool module, that can be very useful.
And there is a very little overhead for creating Thread object.